# How to write Regex pattern to find a string between '=' and before '&' with after last '=' of URL

Tags: java, regression-testing, string

Regex pattern need to find below url values in bold color

http://abc.com/XMLFeed?clientkey=**abtc**&type=**Products**&ProductID=**111**&location=**145**

```
[=**abtc**&
 =**Products**&
 =**111**&
 =**145**]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for code to be written without any explanation of exactly what is wanted. It would not be a good fit for Stack Overfow or Programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex captures all variable parameters in your url. To get the last one, simply iterate through the results.

`(?<==).*?(?=&)`

[Demo here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%3D%29.*%3F%28%3F%3D%26%29&i=http%3A%2F%2Fabc.com%2FXMLFeed%3Fclientkey%3Dabtc%26type%3DProducts%26ProductID%3D111%26location%3D145)

Comment: Your example does not capture last value (145), you should also use capturing group top capture anything.